# What is the best way to handle event parameters using functional programming?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="btn">Click me</button>
<ul class="cont"></ul>

<script>
    function createHtml(str) {
        return `<li>${str}</li>`;
    }

    function insertHtml(document, contClassName, str) {
        document.querySelector(`.${contClassName}`).innerHTML += str;
    }

    function handler() {
        insertHtml(document, 'cont', createHtml(document.querySelector(`.input`).value));
    }

    document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', handler);
</script>
```

I wanted to try to write this more functionally and came up with:

```
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="btn">Click me</button>
<ul class="cont"></ul>

<script>
    function createHtml(str) {
        return `<li>${str}</li>`;
    }

    function insertHtml(document, contClassName, str) {
        document.querySelector(`.${contClassName}`).innerHTML += str;
    }

    function createHandler(createHtml, inputClassName, insertHtml, document, contClassName) {
        return function () {
            insertHtml(document, contClassName, createHtml(document.querySelector(`.${inputClassName}`).value));
        }
    }

    const handler = createHandler(createHtml, 'input', insertHtml, document, 'cont');

    document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', handler);
</script>
```

My main point of uncertainty is the click event handling. Is this a good way to approach this while staying in line with functional programming principles?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: I'd suggest Rx.js as a good way to stay functional in DOM interactions

Comment: Thanks, @DejanToteff. This is very interesting, I hadn't heard of that before.